# How to tell the Android Emulator to use an external hardware device (e.g. a microphone)?

Tags: android, external, microphone

Is it possible to tell the Android Emulator to use external hardware?
In my case, I want to use a Microphone for input for an app I'm developing...

I know about the Emulator start-up commands, but I can't seem to get these working...

Is there anybody who can tell me more about how to use the start-up commands trough Eclipse? Or how to determine which backend I have to specify when using let's say the `-audio-in <backend>` start-up command...

I really need this to work, as I can't debug on the phone I use to test my apps...

Comment: Try a [sample app](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/) the emulator uses the default PC mic settings. See if you can record audio on your PC using a voice rec program

Comment: I am trying to avoid the MediaRecorder class as I need a byte[] and not writing data to a file... I want to use the data directly... not afterwards

Answer (score 0):

For Additional(Start-up) command below is resolution:

got to project->run->run configuration->target->scroll down you will see Additional emulator Command Line Options.......give your additional command here..android will launch emulator with youe specified command

Comment: My question was more so aimed at how the commands are to be used, not where they should be used... But still thank you as I never was able to find that field, but have now...